# Passport.js with Vue Router - Navigation Guard

Tags: javascript, vue.js, passport.js, vue-router

I'm using Vue Router for navigation and passport.js for login/registration for my application. The login/registration system works fine, and are set-up with a mongodb database.

However, I can't get my route protection to work with the passport function for ensuring authentication.

Here is my code so far:

```
const { ensureAuthenticated } = require('../../Configurators/userAuthentication');

const routes = [
{path: '/afterLogin', name: 'AfterLogin', 
component: () => import('../views/afterLogin.vue'), beforeEnter : ensureAuthenticated},
]
```

Here is my authentication function:

```
module.exports = {
    ensureAuthenticated: function(req, res, next) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            return next();
        }
        req.flash('error_msg', 'Please log in to view that resource');
        res.redirect('/users/login');
    }
};
```

I'm very new to Vue Router so any help would be much appreciated.